# android studio - need rss feed example

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I have been trying to implement rss feed on android for two days and fails to  find suitable and simple example here on internet. I did it using WebView but it doesn't match my requirements. Can any one give me simple example that fetches feeds like, image, title, description and date

This app doesnt load anything I cant understand whats the problem

Thanks

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends ListFragment {

//        private TextView mRssFeed;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

//When I uncomment onCreateView it says unfortunately app has stopped

//        @Override
//        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
//                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
//            mRssFeed = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rss_feed);
//            return rootView;
//        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            new GetAndroidPitRssFeedTask().execute();
        }

    private String getAndroidPitRssFeed() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        String rssFeed = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.androidpit.com/feed/main.xml");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)   url.openConnection();
                in = conn.getInputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                for (int count; (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
                rssFeed = new String(response, "UTF-8");
          }finally {
               if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
           }
         }
       return rssFeed;
    }

    private class GetAndroidPitRssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,    List<String>> {

            @Override
            protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                List<String> result = null;
                try {
                    String feed = getAndroidPitRssFeed();
                    result = parse(feed);
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            private List<String> parse(String rssFeed) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                xpp.setInput(new StringReader(rssFeed));
                xpp.nextTag();
                return readRss(xpp);
            }

            private List<String> readRss(XmlPullParser parser)
                    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "rss");
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    String name = parser.getName();

                    if (name.equals("channel")) {
                        items.addAll(readChannel(parser));
                    } else {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
              }
              return items;
          }

          private List<String> readChannel(XmlPullParser parser)
                    throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
                List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "channel");
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("item")) {
                        items.add(readItem(parser));
                    } else {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
                }
                return items;
            }

            private String readItem(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                String result = null;
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "item");
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("title")) {
                        result = readTitle(parser);
                    } else {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
                }


      return result;
        }

        // Processes title tags in the feed.
        private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser)
                throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "title");
            String title = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "title");
            return title;
            }



 private String readText(XmlPullParser parser)
                throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
            String result = "";
            if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                result = parser.getText();
                parser.nextTag();
            }
            return result;
        }

            private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }
                int depth = 1;
                while (depth != 0) {
                    switch (parser.next()) {
                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                            depth--;
                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                            depth++;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<String> rssFeed) {
                if (rssFeed != null) {
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
                            getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            rssFeed));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is fragment_main.xml contains relativelayout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rss_feed"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="arittek.com.androidpitrss.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try reading this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: At least add your code here so others can help you out or your question will soon be marked close.

Comment: I need a simple example @Jul 55

Comment: @AamirShaikh: Show your code, show your effort. AndroidStudio or Eclipse is just IDE. You only need logic code which is provided in [Eliahu Horwitz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38323454/1050058)

Answer (score 1):

I have found these two projects useful:

https://github.com/ShirwaM/Simplistic-RSS

https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library

You can download them and customize to your needs(ATOM/RSS/media etc)

Comment: I have tried both these links already these are too old and doesn't use gradle. @Eliahu Horwitz

Comment: Just download the source code and include I. Android studio, then use the objects as shown

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me [Simple-Rss2-Android](https://github.com/salendron/Simple-Rss2-Android)

```
SimpleRss2Parser parser = new SimpleRss2Parser("http://pingeb.org/feed", 
    new SimpleRss2ParserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFeedParsed(List<RSSItem> items) {
            for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
                Log.d("SimpleRss2ParserDemo",items.get(i).getTitle());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
);
parser.parseAsync();
```

Comment: Its not working means it doesn't show the feeds I also tried after removing button and pasting the your code in onCreate in activity_main file